# Need regex to get domain + subdomain

Tags: regex, dns, subdomain

So im using this function here:

```
function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

$referer = get_domain($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

And what i need is another regex for it, if someone would be so kind to help.
Exactly what i need is for it to get the whole domain, including subdomains.

Lets say as a real problem i have now. When people blogging link from example: myblog.blogger.com
The referer url will be just blogger.com, which is not ideal..

So if someone could help me so i can get the including subdomain as regex code for the function above, id apreciate it alot!

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just `return isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';`?

Comment: could you tell me how $domain before passing it to the regex?

Answer (score 12):

This regex should match a domain in a string, including any dubdomains:

```
/([a-z0-9|-]+\.)*[a-z0-9|-]+\.[a-z]+/
```

Translated to rough english, it functions like this: "match the first part of the string that has 'sometextornumbers.sometext', and also include any number of 'sometextornumbers.' that might preceed it.

See it in action here: http://regexr.com?2vppk

Note that the multiline and global flags in that link are only there to be able to match the entire blob of test-text, so you don't need if you're passing only one line to the regex

Comment: domain and subdomain also can contain dash(-)

Comment: Per RFC, hostname labels cannot begin or end with a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with the above as Domain names now contain non-roman characters. These would have to be processed into equivalent but unique ascii before regex could work reliably. See RFC 3490 Internationalizing Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) ...
See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490
which has

> Until now, there has been no standard method for domain names to use
> characters outside the ASCII repertoire.  This document defines
> internationalized domain names (IDNs) and a mechanism called
> Internationalizing Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) for handling
> them in a standard fashion.  IDNs use characters drawn from a large
> repertoire (Unicode), but IDNA allows the non-ASCII characters to be
> represented using only the ASCII characters already allowed in so-
> called host names today.  This backward-compatible representation is
> required in existing protocols like DNS, so that IDNs can be
> introduced with no changes to the existing infrastructure.  IDNA is
> only meant for processing domain names, not free text.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is an optimization for the first suggestion.
The main improvements:

- does not react to invalid pattern `sub..domain.xyz`

- captures more that one sub-domain as group
- captures port if given

```
https://((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)*)([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+)($|\s|\:\d{1,5})
```

Test it: https://regex101.com/r/njFIil/1

This regex does not handle any unicode symbols, which *could* be a problem as mentioned above.

Comment: Your expression does not work without a port number, as show here: https://regex101.com/r/RZSKc1/1 - you should make it optional. Also, adding a | in the brackets allows to use it. I created you many examples here: https://regex101.com/r/W93YdL/1

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback!
I improved the regex, it reacts correct to all of your tests except for your first 'invalid' domain, which doesn't seem wrong to me.

Answer (score -2):

Better solution:

```
/^([a-z0-9|-]+[a-z0-9]{1,}\.)*[a-z0-9|-]+[a-z0-9]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,}$/
```

Regex sample: 
https://regexr.com/4k71a

And for email address:

```
/^[a-z0-9|.|-]+[a-z0-9]{1,}@([a-z0-9|-]+[a-z0-9]{1,}\.)*[a-z0-9|-]+[a-z0-9]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,}$/
```

Comment: Why and how is this better? It matches `|||||||a.zzzzzz` for example. Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: this would be only valid for two-char toplevel domain names. what about "vienna", "berlin" or "com"?