# Python code to search Google returns an empty list of results

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have written the following code, which attempts to search Google using Beautiful Soup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
def search_error(statement):
    print("Googling.......")
    google_search = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + statement)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.text, 'html.parser')
    search_result = soup.select(".r a")

    for link in search_result:
        print(link)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    statement = input("Enter the Statement of Error to find it on Stack Overflow: ")
    search_error(statement)
```

However, the code is not returning the expected output. The `search_result` variable is equal to an empty list, whereas I expected it to contain all of the search results.

What is wrong with this code, and how should I modify it to obtain all the search results for the keyword `statement`?

Answer (score 0):

The search_result is empty because you are passing text and not the content of the HTML to the parser(BeautifulSoup). Try sending the content,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.content, 'html.parser')
search_result = soup.find_all('a',{"data-uch":1})
```

That should probably do the trick.

Comment: Check what the soup variable is returning. Also you can check what the status code for the google_search get request is. Normally the request.get should fetch you a 200,Ok!

Comment: can you please give me your email address or instagram or FB I can send you screenshot and stuff. Need support.

Answer (score 0):

Please print the soup variable and attach the output. Because when I run your code, and printing **soup** variable. it shows -

```
Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.  This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot.
```

maybe that's why you're getting any result using  **soup.select(".r a")** .

Attach the output after printing soup variable's value so we can see what you're getting .

Comment: When I write KCrYT instead of .r it gives right answer!

Comment: Okay Shubh. It means you've already solved this question. So answer it below and close this one.

Comment: but sir i am not able to understand one thing

Comment: In Google when I inspect the page
It shows the class 'r' and when I just do soup.prettyify() it shows the class kCrYT so why this Google page shows other?

When I put '.r a' it doesn't give any output. Then why Google shows 'r' class

Comment: I am also not sure, I have to look into it. Maybe the result showed in inspect windows is somewhat different when we use request method.  Again i will look into that

Comment: Yes sure please sir and please even explain me that too

Answer (score 0):

It's because:

1. no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) is specified thus Google will block a request eventually. [What is my `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)
2. no attribute specified while extracting links in a `for` loop, e.g `['href']` attribute.

Code:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
def search_error(statement):

    headers = {
        'User-agent':
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={statement}", headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
    search_result = soup.select(".yuRUbf")

    for link in search_result:
        print(link.a['href'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    statement = input("Enter the Statement of Error to find it on Stack Overflow: ")
    search_error(statement)

-------------
'''
Enter the Statement of Error to find it on Stack Overflow: regex match subdomain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930751/regexp-for-subdomain/7933253
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272892/regex-to-match-all-subdomains-of-a-matched-domains
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158962/grep-and-regex-filter-subdomains-in-a-file
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you would only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want, rather than figuring out how to extract things and understand why Google isn't returning what you were looking for.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

def search_error(statement):
    params = {
      "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
      "engine": "google",
      "q": statement,
      "hl": "en"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    for result in results['organic_results']:
      print(result['link'])
      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    statement = input("Enter the Statement of Error to find it on Stack Overflow: ")
    search_error(statement)

-------------
'''
Enter the Statement of Error to find it on Stack Overflow: regex match subdomain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930751/regexp-for-subdomain
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959765/need-regex-to-get-domain-subdomain/8959842
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158962/grep-and-regex-filter-subdomains-in-a-file
...
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Organic Search](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.